# how to display all user selected "options" in a list

Tags: php

I need the user to select one, two, three or four items from a drop down list and then display them in the "ul". I have the number of the selected item displayed and I need the value to be displayed.

**my code**

```
 <select name="courses" size="4" multiple>
        <option>BMW</option>
        <option>Mercedes</option>
        <option>Audi</option>
        <option>Volvo</option>
 </select>

 <?php
 if(!isset($_POST["courses"])) {
     echo 'error';
 } else {
     echo '<ul><li>' . implode('</li><li>', $_POST["courses"]) . '</li></ul>';
 }...
```

do not judge strictly, I am new to php thanks in advance

Comment: check what is in $_POST:  print_r($_POST);. You will be able to seen how PHP receives the posted value(s). You do POST (and not GET) the form, do you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `name="courses"` attribute to `name="courses[]"`, then it will be passed to $_POST and treated as an array, not as single value string.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="courses[]" size="4" multiple>
    <option>BMW</option>
    <option>Mercedes</option>
    <option>Audi</option>
    <option>Volvo</option>
```

Making the `name attribute "courses"` an array would solve the problem